# Clips rule for an object going into infinite loop after modifying the content inside it

Tags: clips

I am incrementing the variable inside an clips object by some number on RHS.

The rule is working, but going into infinite loop.

I tried running it without modifying the variable inside the object, it is coming into RHS once, but with modification it is going into loop.

```
(defrule modify
        "modify"
        (step 0)
        ?EA <- (object (is-a ALERT)
                (ID                      ?RID&:(or(eq ?ID "R") (eq ?RID "Q")))
                (TIME                     ?T)
        )
        =>
        (bind ?time (send ?EA get-TIME))
        (bind ?newTime (+ 86399 ?time))
        (send ?EA put-TIME ?newTime)
        (log_info (str-cat "old time is " ?time ", new time is " ?newTime "event time is " (send ?EA get-TIME)))
)
```

I am expecting the log to be printed once even after modifying the content inside object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the Slot on the LHS which we are incrementing on RHS fixed this.

```
(defrule modify
        "modify"
        (step 0)
        ?EA <- (object (is-a ALERT)
                (ID                      ?RID&:(or(eq ?ID "R") (eq ?RID "Q")))                
        )
        =>
        (bind ?time (send ?EA get-TIME))
        (bind ?newTime (+ 86399 ?time))
        (send ?EA put-TIME ?newTime)
        (log_info (str-cat "old time is " ?time ", new time is " ?newTime "event time is " (send ?EA get-TIME)))
)
```

If we keep slot TIME in LHS, after the change/increment the rule is getting re-triggered, and it is going in loop.